# Transform not working - right click acts like grab: what am I missing?

Tags: vertices, edges

I'm newish to Blender, following a Udemy course. Everything has been working fine, but now suddenly when I'm in edit mode and select a vertice / edge / face, the right click just **drags the entire object around** instead of transforming the object by moving the vertice / edge / face.

I don't mean that proportional editing is turned on (it was suggested that this has been answered elsewhere). This is not the same question. The entire object moves - with no changes or transforming actions. **Dragging any vertice of face behaves like grab: the entire object moves.**

Does anyone know why this might be happening?

Have I accidentally messed up a setting somewhere?

I added another mesh in the same file and I have the same problem. I opened a new file and created a mesh there and it works fine, so it's not my input device - I've obviously done something in this file that I don't understand.
If anyone has any siggestions to help me troubleshoot this, I would appreciate it. And apologies if I'm missing something that should be obvious.
Thanks!
Georgie

As requested, this is the viewport:

[image: viewport]

You can see the vertex selected. Clicking on this to transform it just grabs the whole object. I'm not pressing G to grab.

Comment: "The entire object moves - with no changes or transforming actions" object can't move by itself. Either it's all selected and moved with G tool or Proportional edit is turned on. One more possibility is that you selected all the mesh and used right click which activates Grab tool that moves the selection. Show some screenshots of your whole 3d viewport.

Comment: Proportional Edit is turned on. See bottom of the 3d viewport (bottom line on yor screenshot), grey button with blue circle in the middle. Press O to turn it off (if it doesn't turn off immediately press O again). Whole mesh might be moved because radius of Proportional Edit is very high. G tool is not the only way to grab

Comment: Thank you. I had tried turning it off before but it didn't work - it must have been the radius that was causing the entire mesh to move. It didn't look like the example in the other post about proportional edit at all. Thank you for the clarification.